How to deploy a model on Seldon Core v2 using grpcurl?
I'm trying to deploy a model to Seldon Core (v2) using grpcurl.
My operating system is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I installed Seldon Core v2 on Kubernetes (locally) following the steps in the official documentation (https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/v2/contents/getting-started/kubernetes-installation/index.html).
The model is a simple sklearn iris, I followed the guide on the official documentation (https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/v2/contents/models/index.html#grpc-example) but it doesn't work as it should.
I know that you can simply deploy any model using an appropriate yaml file via kubectl (and it works), but since the official documentation says that you can also use grpcurl I don't understand why it doesn't work.
I tried running the following command (the same one present on the official documentation link https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/v2/contents/models/index.html#grpc-example):
grpcurl -d '{"model":{"meta":{"name":"iris"}, "modelSpec":{"uri":"gs://seldon-models/mlserver/iris", "requirements":["sklearn"], "memoryBytes":500}, "deploymentSpec":{"replicas":1}}}' 
-plaintext 
-proto ./scheduler.proto  localhost:8080 seldon.mlops.scheduler.Scheduler/LoadModel
I modified the command appropriately because I launched it from a folder in which the scheduler.proto file (defined in the official documentation https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/v2/contents/apis/scheduler/index.html) is also present.
I get the following error:
ERROR:
Code: Unimplemented
Message:
Maybe the problem is using localhost:8080 as the ip address and port? In the official documentation 0.0.0.0:9004 is used as ip and port, but if I try to put them in the grpcurl command I get the following error:
Failed to dial target host "0.0.0.0:9004": dial tcp 0.0.0.0:9004: connect: connection refused
Am I missing something? The documentation does not mention specific addresses of the scheduler or particular port forwards regarding it. The only port forward that is mentioned is the one related to inference: since I am not using a LoadBalancer for the seldon-mesh Service I execute the following command which allows me to send all inference requests towards localhost:8080:
kubectl port-forward svc/seldon-mesh -n seldon-mesh 8080:80
Furthermore, server reflection is not active, so there is no way I can verify that the scheduler.proto file has the correct methods.
How can i get over this?

Not a programming question and so unsuited to Stack overflow. Your question omits key details as to which Kubernetes platform you're using, how you deployed (Helm? Ansible?) making it difficult to answer. I'm unfamiliar with Seldon Core. The architecture diagram suggests that the gRPC-based "scheduler" is distinct from the regular Ingress so I'd confirm where this service is exposed. It's curious that you get a "Unimplemented Message" error. Your grpcurl appears correct.
